# Problems creating Drupal Commerce Product Display, list of available products not populating

Tags: commerce

This is something that has happened to a site I'm maintaining. I can't create product displays for many of my products because the select list of products in the product field isn't populated with many of my products.

I have a content type called "Product Display" with product field of type product reference. When adding products the select list of products is only display 10 of about 100 products.

This only diagnostic information is that two javascript errors are reported

```
Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'behaviors' of undefind in jquery-noconflict.slicknav
```

And

```
Failed to load resource: Server responded with a status of 403 (forbidden)
```

This leads me to thing it's a jquery issue, but not sure how to debug this further.

So, how do I get that list of products to contain all of the products in the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Drupal Commerce 1.13. I'll be patching it today:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2697017